# How does Deep-Color (10-bit+ per channel) work in Win32?

Tags: winapi, colors

I don't have any Deep-Color capable hardware attached to my computer, so I haven't been able to experiment myself, and searching online for "win32 deep-color" or "win32 10-bit color" (or 30-bit, 48-bit or 64-bit) yields nothing relevant or recent. The top result is still this NVIDIA PDF from 2009: https://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/40049/TB-04701-001_v02_new.pdf - it describes using OpenGL and an NVIDIA API for displaying images with more than 8-bits per channel.

I understand how using OpenGL allows 30-bit color images to be displayed: it effectively bypasses the operating system and the OpenGL surface is rendered in deep-color on the GPU and sent directly to the monitor in an appropriate format over DisplayPort or HDMI.

But what options are there outside of OpenGL?

In Win32, after you create a Window with `CreateWindow`, you render it by handling the `WM_PAINT` message, and then calling `BeginPaint`, which gives you a handle to a GDI device-context, which cannot be more than 32bpp (8-bits per channel).

While GDI ostensibly abstracts away implementation details of the rendering device, including color depth, it is impossible to specify a 10bpp RGB value, for example (the `COLORREF` struct is hardcoded to use 32-bit (8bpp) `DWORD` values), a leaky-abstraction.

Does this mean it is impossible to display 30bpp / Deep-color content in the Windows Desktop using a program handling `WM_PAINT` and that OpenGL is the only way?

And what would happen if you attempted to blit from an in-memory OpenGL rendering buffer back to the window surface? (i.e. what happens if you press PrintScreen while displaying a Deep-Color BluRay disc in a BD player, or displaying 30-bit content in Photoshop?)

Comment: GDI is, cough, feature complete.  Pixel formats supported by DirectX and Direct2D are [listed here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173059(vs.85).aspx).  Note the R10G10B10 formats.

Comment: You can create a window without allocating a client area surface (that's what the [WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) extended window style is for), and create your own DirectX swap chain in place. This allows you to still render in response to `WM_PAINT` messages, albeit not onto the device context returned from `BeginPaint` (which you still need to call to validate the client area, an to get the dirty area that needs to be repainted). Hit testing also works given this setup.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for the link. I noticed that if you do use Non-Redirected Bitmaps then you don't get taskbar thumbnails - is there a way around this?

Comment: Does it show a thumbnail preview, after you created a DirectX swap chain? If it still doesn't, I guess you'll have to provide your own. I haven't played around with this yet, but I believe you could handle the [WM_DWMSENDICONICLIVEPREVIEWBITMAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd938874.aspx) message and call [DwmSetIconicLivePreviewBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389410.aspx) in response, providing a custom live preview. Seems tedious, and somewhat non-trivial to replicate an appropriate window representation.